# How do I get Violation Report (JSON DATA) for Content Security Policy using PHP?

Tags: php, html, post, content-security-policy, raw-post

One helpful feature of [Content Security Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/#content-security-policy-report-only-header-field) is ability to detect violations and sending it to specific URI as (Violation Report). According to documentation from [CSP 1.1 Sec. 3.2.4 Reporting](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/#content-security-policy-report-only-header-field):

> To send violation reports, the user agent must use an algorithm
>   equivalent to the following:
>
> - Fetch report URI from the
>     origin of the protected resource, with the synchronous flag not set,
>     using **HTTP method POST**, with a Content-Type header field of
>     application/json with an entity body consisting of report body. If the
>     origin of report URI is not the same as the origin of the protected
>     resource, the block cookies flag must also be set. The user agent must
>     not follow redirects when fetching this resource. (Note: The user
>     agent ignores the fetched resource.)

#### Then, in section [5.2 Sample Violation Report](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/#sample-violation-report) provided an example:

> In the following example, the user agent rendered a representation of
>   the resource http://example.org/page.html with the following CSP
>   policy:

```
default-src 'self'; report-uri http://example.org/csp-report.cgi
```

> The protected resource loaded an image from
>   http://evil.example.com/image.png, violating the policy.

```
{
  "csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "http://example.org/page.html",
    "referrer": "http://evil.example.com/haxor.html",
    "blocked-uri": "http://evil.example.com/image.png",
    "violated-directive": "default-src 'self'",
    "effective-directive": "img-src",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'self'; report-uri http://example.org/csp-report.cgi"
  }
}
```

#### Example:

**test.php**

```
<?php
header("X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; report-uri http://127.0.0.1/csp-report.php");
?>
<img src="http://evil.example.com/image.png">
```

**csp-report.php**

```
<?php
$content = "
Keys: ".implode("\n", array_keys($_POST))."\n
\n--------------------------\n\n
Values: ".implode("\n", $_POST)."\n
";
file_put_contents('csp-report.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

**csp-report.txt**

```
Keys: 

--------------------------

Values:
```

**As you see, nothing saved in that file!** However, using Firebug, it seems that the report sent to that file:

[image]

**Note: I expect analytical answer mentioning why normal post not working and what alternative should be used, and why? also, providing how to decode a JSON is plus.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no PHP expert, but the POST body is just a chunk of json, so there is no key-value pair. I'm assuming that array_keys is empty. I think you want to json_decode($POST) http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Also, looks like your question is answered in:

[JSON Post in PHP (CSP-Report)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629534/json-post-in-php-csp-report)

> Note: I expect analytical answer mentioning why normal post not working and what alternative should be used, and why?

I'm not sure what you're asking, but as for the "normal" POST, there is nothing in the spec that dictates the content of the post body has to be key-value pairs. Also, a key/value pair in the traditional sense is not valid JSON.

Another possibly helpful page: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html

Comment: Your right, personally, I knew the right answer, which is `file_get_contents("php://input")` can you please add more detail to your answer, its just about raw HTTP post...

Comment: What information are you looking for? What questions do you have?